# Governance voting option for a platform similar to compound that is dynamic and people can make their own options apart from yes/no

Tags: solidity, defi, governance

it should just read the voting power and let people vote between different options. the result needs to be logged,

how can I create a simple smart contract for the 3rd choice or option for people voting?
They can input their own options.

Example : if someone proposes a higher price for the token.
This choice can be YES / No
or a third option for users to input a new price suggestion.

Comment: Do you want the contract to count yes and no votes for each question/proposal and additionally keep a register of free user answers?

Comment: I think your question is too broad for a forum like this. Perhaps you can ask for something more specific?